# Is the book wrong?

Tags: c++

```
template <typename T>
  class Table {
    public:
      Table();
      Table(int m, int n);
      Table(int m, int n, const T& value);
      Table(const Table<T>& rhs);
      ~Table();
      Table<T>& operator=(const Table& rhs);
      T& operator()(int i, int j);
      int numRows()const;
      int numCols()const;
      void resize(int m, int n);
      void resize(int m, int n, const T& value);
    private:
      // Make private because this method should only be used
      // internally by the class.
      void destroy();
    private:
      int mNumRows;
      int mNumCols;
      T** mDataMatrix;
  };

template <typename T>
  void Table<T>::destroy() {
    // Does the matrix exist?
    if (mDataMatrix) {
      for (int i = 0; i < _m; ++i) {
        // Does the ith row exist?
        if (mDataMatrix[i]) {
          // Yes, delete it.
          delete[]mDataMatrix[i];
          mDataMatrix[i] = 0;
        }
      }

      // Delete the row-array.
      delete[] mDataMatrix;
      mDataMatrix = 0;
    }

    mNumRows = 0;
    mNumCols = 0;
  }
```

This is a code sample I got from a book. It demonstrates how to destroy or free a 2x2 matrix where mDataMatrix is the pointer to array of pointers.

What I don't understand is this part:

```
for(int i = 0; i < _m; ++i) {
  // Does the ith row exist?
  if (mDataMatrix[i]) {
    //.….

  }
}
```

I don't know why the book uses _m for max number of row-ptr. It wasn't even a variable define in class; the variable for max row is mNumRows. Maybe it is some compiler pre-defined variable? Another thing I am quite confuse is why is it ++i? pre-operator, why not i++? Will it make different if I change it into i++?

Comment: Is there any more code there? any class definition etc?

Comment: I think you need to post the definition of `mDataMatrix` and `_m`.

Comment: The book is encouraging some bad habits: checking for a null pointer before deleting it, and setting the pointer to null when it's about to be deleted itself. The body of the `for` loop could just as well be `delete [] mDataMatrix[i];`.

Comment: So what's the good habit? Is setting to null after delete[] risky? Then how do I get around with that

Comment: Was the book written by Herbert Schildt?  Because it looks like a lousy book!

Comment: @biloon: not risky, just unnecessary. The final delete will remove the pointers from existence, so it doesn't matter whether they are null or not. A good habit is to only write code that does something useful.

Comment: As a counterpoint, if you're _learning_ C++ (as opposed to an experienced dev), it can be useful to set pointers to NULL after they're deleted so that you can see what you've deleted in the debugger when stepping through your code while learning that you didn't write your copy constructor properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Another thing I am quite confuse is why is it ++i? pre-operator, why not i++? Will it make different if I change it into i++?

Because `++i` is more natural and easier to understand: increment `i` and then yield the variable `i` as a result. `i++` on the other hand means copy the current value of `i` somewhere (let's call it `temp`), increment `i`, and then yield the value `temp` as a result.

Also, for user-defined types, `i++` is potentially slower than `++i`.

Note that `++i` as a loop increment does *not* imply the increment happens before entering the loop body or something. (This seems to be a common misconception among beginners.) If you're not using `++i` or `i++` as part of a larger expression, the semantics are exactly the same, because prefix and postfix increment only differ in their *result* (incremented variable vs. old value), not in their *side effect* (incrementing the variable).

Comment: It's important to note that the number of _real-world_ cases where any theoretical performance difference between `i++` and `++i` matters is _vanishingly_ small.

Comment: @Greg: But `++i` is *never* slower than `i++`. Prefix is *easier to understand* and *potentially faster* than postfix. Why would I ever want to prefer the postfix form? What is the advantage of `i++;` over `++i;`?

Comment: "easier to understand" is fundamentally subjective.  I made no claims about ever preferring one style over the other.  In trivial cases, which the vast majority of uses for this operator are, there is _no performance difference_ and it is a _purely stylistic preference_.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Because the variable, which is what is important, comes first. That's subjective, I admit. But, in my opinion, they're both equally terrible.

Comment: @Greg: I have observed the following pattern when asking people for explanations of the semantics of prefix and postfix forms: If someone really understood postfix, he had absolutely no trouble understanding prefix. However, many people could not explain the semantics of postfix correctly, but still understood prefix. From this I draw the conclusion that prefix is easier to understand than postfix.

Comment: @FredOverflow: That doesn't change the fundamentally subjective nature of what is easier to understand.  Especially in the question's case where they actually _are_ identical.  The amount of cargo cult FUD around the post-increment operator that is justified by "performance" is ridiculous.

Comment: @Greg: I agree with respect to built-in types. But for user-defined types, the compiler is not allowed to optimize `x++` to `++x` because they might have completely different semantics.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing the entire class code, it is hard to tell for your first question, but if it hasn't been defined as part of the class, my guess would be that it is a typo.

as for your second question, ++i vs. i++, the prefix increment operator (++i) returns the object you are incrementing, whereas the postfix increment operator returns a copy of the object, in the objects original state.  i.e.-

```
int i=1;
std::cout << i++ << std::endl;  // output:  1
std::cout << i << std::endl     // output:  2
std::cout << ++i << std::endl   // output:  3
```

as for will the code change with the postfix- no, it works the same in loops, and makes basically no difference in loops for integer types.  For user defined types, however, it may be more efficient to use the prefix increment, and is the style many c++ programmers use by default.

Answer (score 2):

If the `_m`variable isn't defined anywhere this is an error. From that context it looks like it should contain the number of rows that are allocated with `new` somewhere (probably in the constructor, or there might be methods like `addRow`). If that number is always `mNumRows`, than this would be appropriate for the loop in the destructor.

If you use `++i` or `i++` in that for loop doesn't make any difference. Both variants increment the integer, and the return value of the expression (that would be different) isn't used anywhere.

Comment: I agree. As two constructors use the parameters `m`, and `n`, I think that `_m` is the instance variable that contains the value of `m`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the first part of the question, but I can explain the pre- versus post- increment dilemma.

Prefix versions increment and decrement are slightly more efficient and are generally preferred.  In the end, though, the extra overhead caused by using i++ over ++i is negligible unless the loop is being executed many, many times.

Comment: On any modern compiler with optimization there is _no_ difference between trivial pre-incrementing and post-incrementing an integer in a `for` loop.  The generated code is identical.  There isn't even a "slight" efficiency difference.  They are the same.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the prefix operator is preferred for performance reasons when dealing with user-defined types.  The reason it has no impact on the `for` loop is because the test involving the value of the variable (i.e. `i < _m)` is performed before the operation that modifies the variable is performed.

Answer (score 0):

The real mess with this book is the way it illustrates a 2x2 matrix. The problem is here that for 4 elements you have 3 blocks of memory allocated, and not only does it slows down the program but it is certainly much more tricky to handle.

The usual technic is much simpler:

```
T* mData = new T[2*2];
```

And then you access it like so:

```
T& operator()(size_t r, size_t c) { return mData[r * mNbRows + c]; }
```

This is a bit more work (you have to multiply by the number of rows if you are row major), but then the `destroy` is incredibly easy:

```
template <class T>
void Table<T>::destroy()
{
  delete[] mData;
  mData = 0;
  mNbRows = 0;
  mNbColumns = 0;
}
```

Also note that here there is no need for a `if`: it's fine to call `delete` on a null pointer, it just doesn't do anything.

Finally, I have no idea why your book is using `int` for coordinates, do negative coordinates have any meaning in the context of this `Table` class ? If not, you're better off using an unsigned integral type (like `size_t`) and throwing the book away.